# How can I hide the sound and full screen button in react-native-video

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios, react-native-video

Any option to hide the sound and fullscreen icon in video screen. I am using react-native-video package.

[image]

Comment: This needs an answer!

Comment: did you ever find out a solution?